# Thread seems to be blocking the process

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multithreading

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def start(self):
        colorThread = threading.Thread(target = self.colorIndicator())
        colorThread.start() 

        while True:
            print ('something')
            ...
            ...
```

I also have a `print` statement inside the `colorIndicator()`. That statement is getting printed. But the print statement inside the while loop of `start()` method isn't displayed on screen.

The `colorIndicator()` also has an infinite loop. It gets some data from the internet and updates a counter. This counter is initialized inside `__init__` as  `self` variable and I'm using that variable inside other methods.

I do not understand why `print` inside while is not being executed.

colorIndicator function:

```
def colorIndicator(self):
        print ('something else')
        ...
        while (True):
            ...
            print ('here')
        time.sleep(25)
```

The output I get is the following:

```
something else
here
here
```

I stopped it after that. So, the colorIndicator is clearly running completely.
I'm calling the script with `import` in a python interpreter (in a terminal). Then I instantiate `MyClass` and call the `start` function.

Comment: can you post your `colorIndicator` function?

Comment: @Skam I have posted it now.

Comment: Sorry and your `main` function or however you're calling this class and its methods that give you the provided output

Comment: Yes. I import it into the python interpreter and then instantiate the class and call the start method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually running `colorIndicator` in a thread, because you *called* it in the main thread, rather than passing the method itself (uncalled) as the thread `target`. Change:

```
    colorThread = threading.Thread(target=self.colorIndicator())
    #                                                        ^^ Agh! Call parens!
```

to:

```
    # Remove parens so you pass the method, without calling it
    colorThread = threading.Thread(target=self.colorIndicator)
    #                                                        ^ Note: No call parens
```

Basically, your problem is that before you ever construct the `Thread`, it's trying to run `colorIndicator` to completion so it can use its return value as the `target`, which is wrong in multiple ways (the method never returns, and even if it did, it wouldn't return a callable suitable for use as a `target`).