# What is wrong with this multiprocessing example?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Based on [this pretty useful tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lu5LrKh1Zno) I have tried to make a simple implementation of Python `multiprocessing` to measure its effectivity. The modules `multi1`, `multi2`, `multi3` contain an ODE integration and exporting the calculated values in a csv (it does not matter, they are here for a script to do something).

```
import multiprocessing
import multi1
import multi2
import multi3
import time

t0 = time.time()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = multi1.main(), args=())
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = multi2.main(), args=())
    p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target = multi3.main(), args=())

    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p3.start()

    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    p3.join()

t1 = time.time()

multi1.main()
multi2.main()
multi3.main()

t2 = time.time()

print t1-t0
print t2-t1
```

The problem is that the printed times are equal, so the `multiprocessing` didn't speed up the process. Why?

Comment: I think it is because join blocks the main process and since you are calling it for each subprocess it became synchronous. https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join

Comment: @PieOhPah: That would only be a problem if they were calling `join` immediately for each worker; if they `start` all workers first, then `join`, the three workers would run in parallel. Blocking the main process would be the intent after all; otherwise you're not timing the time taken for the run (because the workers would not be finished yet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *called* `main` in the main thread, and passed the return value (probably `None`) as the `target`, so no actual work is done in your worker processes. Remove the call parens, so you pass the function itself without calling it, e.g.:

```
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=multi1.main, args=())
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=multi2.main, args=())
p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=multi3.main, args=())
```

This is the same basic problem seen in [the threaded case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45830301/364696).